# Does Sahi an Open Source Automation Testing Tool works with websites built on EmberJs?

Tags: ember.js, automated-tests, sahi

I have a website which is built using emnberjs framework. I tried to run sahi automation testing tool against the website and record test scripts. I see sahi is not able to record the fields are any elements present on the website ,was just wondering about whether sahi actually works with websites built with such frontend frameworks( EmberJs,DustJs etc) ?

Any insight on this is greatly appreciated

Comment: Try it out and let us know.

Comment: Is there is shadow root involved, it won't work. That support is present in the professional version. Else it will work.

Comment: @VivekVDwivedi Thanks for the info , how can i check whether shadow root is involved in the ember implementation ? are there any specific tags which i can lookup in the implementation whether shadow dom/ root is involved ?

Comment: Looks like ember is not using it right now. Can you post a link to the web app or a sample present online where you can replicate the same issue?